# Android multiple asynctasks to fetch network responses instead of one

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, network-programming

This is more of a higher level understanding question.

What I'm trying to do now is run an Asynctask which serially executes 6 methods, each of which is a distinct network request to retrieve data. I was wondering if instead of having 1 asynctask execute these requests serially, would it reduce query overhead and fetch time if I were to separate out all the 6 methods into their OWN Asynctasks and execute them serially so as to create 6 background threads instead?

I'm using URLConnection and InputStreamReader to fetch data now. Would such an implementation be allowed by the Android System? And if it is, would it even improve performance in terms of wait time required to retrieve all the data from the various network calls?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, AsyncTasks execute on a single thread serially even if you start multiple instances together. If you want to run them in parallel, you will want to use something like

```
if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ) {
    new MyAsyncTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
} else {
    new MyAsyncTask().execute();
}
```

For faster results and the ability to easily run multiple queries, consider using a networking library like [Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit) instead of an AsyncTask, as they handle common issues like orientation changes as well.